# NameError: global name 'linear' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run an implementation of attention mechanism by Google DeepMind. However it is based on an older version of TensorFlow and I am getting this error

> from tensorflow.models.rnn.rnn_cell import RNNCell, linear
> concat = linear([inputs, h, self.c], 4 * self._num_units, True)
>
> **NameError: global name 'linear' is not defined**

I couldn't find the linear model/function in the new tensorflow documentation. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Which version are you using? did you try `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` ?

Comment: Thanks @martianwars !!. I couldn't find the tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear function

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer I just added if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` function to make the code work. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html) for a sample usage.